# One to One relationship with axon framework

Tags: spring-boot, cqrs, axon

I'm new to Axon Framework. I've a requirement within an asset management module which I am working on.
In this module different types of asset are build, which need to be paired in a similar fashion as one to one relationships in SQL. I am finding it difficult to design an Aggregate for this format.

The business logic validation is as follows:
Two `assetId`s are inputs. These identifiers resemble aggregate identifiers.
Then, load the asset instances tied to these `assetId`s and check if the status is unpaired or paired. If both the assets are unpaired then pair them (update the status to paired and add UUID to associatedAssets). Else raise an exception.

I have come up with the following Aggregate class:

```java
@Aggregate
@Data
public class AssetAggregate {
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private UUID assetId;
    private String assetType;
    private HashMap<String,String> attributes;
    private String status;
    private String modifier;
    private UUID associatedAsset;
}
```

My Command Message for pairing is this:

```java
@Data
public class PairAssetCommand {
    private UUID assetAId;
    private UUID assetBId;
}
```

Comment: I feel your question is a little to generic at this stage @DarshuBc. Try adding a sample of the Query Model and the Command Model, describing your domain a little. At this stage, I could answer a 1000 different options, none if which would likely bring the needed info to figuring out "how to create a command model". Bit of a plug from my part, but maybe you should check this quickstart video guide on Axon - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4O1nDpoa5KQkkApGXjKi3rzUW3II5pjm

Comment: @Steven I have edited my question thanks for the URL of Video guide

Answer (score 0):

In the sample you have given, the `PairAssetsCommand` can not be handled by a single `AssetAggregate` as it spans the consistency boundary of two distinct aggregate instances. Namely, two different `AssetAggregate`s.

Note that the Aggregate defines the consistency boundary within your command model. Thus any command taken in by it and all it's resulting events (and following state changes) will be regarded as an atomic operation. Making associations between several entities through this can mean two things:

1. You create a bigger Aggregate class which spans **all** `AssetAggregate`s.
2. You have a [External Command Handler](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/external-command-handler) (i.e. a `@CommandHandler` outside of an Aggregate) which handles the `PairAssetsCommand`.

I'd advise against option one, as it will enlarge the consistency boundary towards the entire set of assets in your system. This will eventually become a major bottleneck the maintain an Aggregate's requirement of "keeping the consistency boundary".

That thus leaves option 2. Let's rephrase the business logic you have defined:

> if both the assets are unpaired then pair them(update the status to paired and add UUID to associatedAssets) else raise an exception

This means you cannot validate on a single instance, but need to do this on several. Again, you can take two routes to solving this:

1. Dispatch a `AssociateWithAssetCommand` to both the `AssetAggregate`s and dispatch a compensating command if one of the `AssetAggregate`s is already associated.
2. Use [set based validation](https://danielwhittaker.me/2017/10/09/handle-set-based-consistency-validation-cqrs/) in the external command handler handling the `PairAssetsCommand` to validate your business logic.

Which of the two is best is left to preference I'd say. Solution two requires you to have a small query model containing a set of assets and their association status'. Added, this query model needs to be updated in *the same transaction* as when the association commands occur. Thus, somewhat more complicated.

Hence solution one would be the simplest way to go in your scenario.